# Why are list choice columns disabled in Quick Edit on SharePoint 2019?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am viewing a List of a Site Content type (List item) in Quick Edit mode on a custom view, with several Choice and Lookup Site Columns that allow fill in choices and multiple values.  These columns are disabled for new items - they have grey borders and no drop down appears when entering the cell.  However, for existing items the Lookup columns do work when editing an previously added item (although not the Choice columns).

The desired behaviour here is to have the choice columns work the same in both new and existing items in Quick View.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's by design that you can't use Allow 'Fill-in' choices with Checkboxes (allow multiple selections) in Quick Edit.

Comment: That seems odd - do you know why that was the design decision?

Comment: And why is it different for adding a new item (no selections allowed at all) from editing an existing one (only fill in choices disabled)?

Comment: This is based on SharePoint design and we cannot change it,the available options to use Quick Edit for the choice field: Use Checkboxes (allow multiple selections) without Allow 'Fill-in' choices or Use Drop-Down Menu or Radio Buttons with Allow 'Fill-in' choices

Comment: Thank you @Julie_MSFT